# How can I test styled components?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

What I need to test is `LoginWrapper` always renders inside `Login` component. I test it as follow but it does not pass since `LoginWrapper` cannot be found.

```
  import React from 'react';
  import Login from '../components/Login';

  import Wrapper from '../components/Wrapper';
  import styled from 'styled-components';

  describe('test login', () => {

    const shallowRender = (props) => shallow(<Login {...props} />);
    let LoginWrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
      LoginWrapper = styled(Wrapper)``;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
    });

    it('always render LoginWrapper', () => {
      const login = shallowRender({
        onSubmit: () => {}
      });
      const divs = login.find(LoginWrapper);
      expect(divs).toHaveLength(1);
    });

  });
```

Login.js

```
  import React from 'react';
  import Wrapper from './Wrapper';
  import { H5, Text, ALink } from '@lendi/lendi-components';
  import styled from 'styled-components';

  const LoginWrapper = styled(Wrapper)`
    .mobile {
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .signup {
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
  `;

  function Login ({onSubmit}) {
      return (
        <LoginWrapper>
          <H5 style={style.center}>
            {txt.title}
          </H5>
        </LoginWrapper>
        );
    }

export default Login;
```

It appears `LoginWrapper` will be rendered like `<Styled(styled.div)>` then what is the correct way to find it?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: It's actually rendered as `Styled(Wrapper)`. How about using `displayName` for `LoginWrapper` as selector. Something around  `login.find(LoginWrapper.displayName);`

Comment: You need to import the `LoginWrapper` component in your test. `import LoginWrapper from '../components/LoginWrapper';` That's the first step and take it from there.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thanks for your comments. But `login.find()` always return something which I cannot test properly when passing in a nonexistent styled component. Any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem and question.  Even if you do something like:
`wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
expect(wrapper.find(LoginWrapper)).to.contain.text('Some Text');`

You get an error like:
`expected the node in <LoginWrapper/> to contain text 'Some text', but it has '<styled.div />'`

Comment: @worker11811 I talked to my colleague about this and he suggested that the potential way to test it might require us to mock up the `styled` function.

Comment: @worker11811 In the meantime, I will probably lodge a request on their github issues section to see if I can get any advice from there.

Comment: @worker11811 Hey mate. See link below 

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/877

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting LoginWrapper display name to `LoginWrapper` using this:

```
LoginWrapper.displayName = 'LoginWrapper'
```

to override the display name of your component. This is due to Style Component is a HOC and your component name will change if you wrapped your component with it.

Another thing is you need to delete these lines in your test case as it doesn't help:

```
let LoginWrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  LoginWrapper = styled(Wrapper)``;
});

afterEach(() => {
});
```

and change the following your `find` from `const divs = login.find(LoginWrapper);` to a string like this `const divs = login.find('LoginWrapper');`

I hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when looking for ideas on how to test styled components. Though pretty late, I would like to answer the question in the hope that it might help someone.

**Note:** From the question, I see that OP used `enzyme` library for the test. However, it is better to use `@testing-library/react` instead, because it provides a more intuitive API.

1. Remove redefining the `LoginWrapper` in the test. Otherwise, the tests would use the locally defined component instead of the actual component, which normally is undesirable.

```
let LoginWrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  LoginWrapper = styled(Wrapper)``;
});
```

2. Export `LoginWrapper` from `Login.js`.

```
// Login.js
export const LoginWrapper = styled(Wrapper)`
// Rest of the code left out for brevity
```

3. Assign a `data-testid` to the styled component in the test, and find the component using the same.

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { LoginWrapper } from '../components/Login';

describe('test login', () => {

  it('always render LoginWrapper', () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn();

    render(<LoginWrapper onSubmit={onSubmit} data-testid="login-wrapper" />);

    const loginWrapper = screen.getByTestId('login-wrapper');

    expect(loginWrapper).toBeVisible();
  });

});
```

**Bonus:**

You could test that the styles are applied to the styled component as expected.

```
  it('should have 5px left padding', () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn();

    render(<LoginWrapper onSubmit={onSubmit} data-testid="login-wrapper" />);

    const loginWrapper = screen.getByTestId('login-wrapper');
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(loginWrapper);

    expect(style.paddingLeft).toBe('5px');
  });
```